# Is it possible to split the text of a gt spanner column over multiple lines?

Tags: r, gt

Is it possible to split the text of a `gt` spanner column over multiple lines? Take the following example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

exibble %>%
  dplyr::select(date, time, char, row) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "row") %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "dates and times",
    columns = c(date, time)
  )
```

[image: image of gt table generated by code]

Here, I would like "dates and times" to be split over two (or three) lines. Is it possible to do that?

The following, using "\n" does not work:

```
exibble %>%
  dplyr::select(date, time, char, row) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "row") %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "dates\nand\ntimes",
    columns = c(date, time)
  )
```

Comment: Try sth like 'dates\nand\ntimes' which adds manual line breaks after each word.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I updated with a reprex of your proposed fix (adding "\n").

Comment: Nevermind, just saw that the `exibble` object is already an example of the gt package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

exibble %>%
    dplyr::select(date, time, char, row) %>%
    gt(rowname_col = "row") %>%
    tab_spanner(
        label = html("dates<br> and <br>times"),
        columns = c(date, time)
    )
```

[image]